# Azure FaceAPI limits iteration to 20 items

Tags: azure, iteration, azure-cognitive-services, rate-limiting, face-api

I have a list of image urls from which I use MS Azure faceAPI to extract some features from the photos. The problem is that whenever I iterate more than 20 urls, it seems not to work on any url after the 20th one. There is no error shown. However, when I manually changed the range to iterate the next 20 urls, it worked.

Side note, on free version, MS Azure Face allows only 20 requests/minute; however, even when I let time sleep up to 60s per 10 requests, the problem still persists.

FYI, I have 360,000 urls in total, and sofar I have made only about 1000 requests.

Can anyone help tell me why this happens and how to solve this? Thank you so much!

```
# My codes

i = 0

for post in list_post[800:1000]:
    i += 1
    try:
        image_url = post['photo_url']
        headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': KEY}
        params = {
            'returnFaceId': 'true',
            'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
            'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise',
        }
        response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers, json={"url": image_url})
        post['face_feature'] = response.json()[0]
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        continue
    if i % 10 == 0:
        time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: Please be more precise: which method from Face API are you using? Detect? If you face a quota limit, there will be an error (a 429 response for example). If you have 360 000 url to process, switch to standard price (20 calls / second => take 5hours to process). You can also use several Face API keys to parallelize more calls

Comment: Hi Nicolas, Yes I'm using Detect method, with the instruction here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/python. I know that with my goal of 360K images, I have to upgrade to Standard version, but that's another story. My immediate concern here is not the quota limit, but rather the operation of the call. For example, in my code as above, I iterated 200 images; it took about 10s to result output. Actually, however, it only processed the first 20 images; the rest 180 images were left unprocessed.

Comment: Looping the way you are doing it is waiting for the response of each call before doing the next one (so it is inefficient). And also as said, the 180 « no result » should contain an information (for example in the response code) but you are not reading it here

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thank you for your comments. I am a newbie here so my code might be not efficient. Will appreciate if you can help rewrite the code to make it more efficient? Thank you so much!

Comment: Regarding the latter 180 images, I hope I understand your point. The reason why I thought it didn't read the latter 180 images was that when I reran the next 20 images (among these 180 images), it gave me output.

Answer (score 0):

The free version has a max of 30 000 request per month, your 356 000 faces will therefore take a year to run.

The standard version costs USD 1 per 1000 requests, giving a total cost of USD 360. This option supports 10 transactions per second.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/cognitive-services/face-api/

Comment: Hi Shiraz, thank you for the information. I am aware of the transaction limit for free version, but the problem here is from the beginning I encountered a limit of 20 images in each iteration. Until now I have only made around 1000 requests. I only hope I can run an iteration of more than 20 images in the first 30,000 requests.

Comment: You could try adding a 30 second wait between each call

Comment: As I mentioned on the post, I already tried the 60s time sleep (and also tried shorter times) but the problem still persisted

Comment: You did 60s every 10th call. I meant to move it to between each call

Comment: I got it.
I have tried as you suggested for a range of 100 items and it had ran for like a couple of minutes until shown an error: [the error message is too long, so I will post only the beginning and the end]

ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='azure-face-reddit.cognitiveservices.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /face/v1.0/detect?.....
......VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fcd3897e050>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known'))

Comment: On a side note, this time, it actually worked for like 40 images (yeahhhh).
I guess the above error might be because it took so long to run?

Comment: Okay new update: when I iterated the next 60 images, it ran smoothly without error. I checked the result and yes, it read all 60 images. I remember in previous running, I let my computer sleep; maybe that's why it resulted in the error as above? [Errno 8]